# Get an element hidden by javascript using in a PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, web-crawler

I'm trying to fetch the emails addresses of [an event](http://www.housewares.org/HousewaresConnect365/Results?SearchType=Country&SearchTerm=USA)

EXHIBITOR -- RETURNED 1011 RESULTS

I've coded a PHP crawler to get [each page](http://www.housewares.org/HousewaresConnect365/Detail?com_uid=81766&searchTerm=USA&searchType=Country&comname=6%2BIdeas%252c%2BInc.)

But I need to hover the "Email general company email" with my mouse to display the email address. I would like to do it automatically through my crawler.

We can see the js functions in the code

```
function fixEmail(mungedAddress) {
    Address = mungedAddress;
    var sAddress = decode(mungedAddress);
    $('#Email').attr('href', 'mailto:' + sAddress);

}

function unfixEmail() {
    $('#Email').attr('href', "javascript:void(0);");

}
```

I'm pretty lost about what I could do

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Chris I believe the question is how to circumvent the code of the website that has been designed to prevent precisely this sort of thing.

Comment: @JamesThorpe seems legit

Comment: @JamesThorpe This is exactly what I'm trying to do
And so my question would be that I request the page but I don't get the hidden content. I'm just looking for a way to get those emails, simply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the encoded value, which is the parameter sent to FixEmail function.

```
<a id="Email" onmouseover="fixEmail('SOMERANDOMENCODEVALUEINHERE');" onmouseout="unfixEmail();" href="javascript:void(0);">Email general company email</a>
```

Then just recreate the functionality of the decode function in php, its also visible in the code.

```
function decode(ServerEncoded) {
        var res = "";
        for (i = 0; i < ServerEncoded.length; ) {
            var letter = "";
            letter = ServerEncoded.charAt(i) + ServerEncoded.charAt(i + 1)
            res += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(letter, 16));
            i += 2;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

And thats it.

Comment: This is it! Thanks mate